# filename in sql procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this working in T-SQL

insert into provaxml  (arquivo)

```
sELECT  CAST(BulkColumn AS XML) FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\2012-09\myfile.xml', SINGLE_BLOB)as arquivo
```

i m trying to write a procedure :

```
alter proc adentro (@nome nvarchar(max))as
insert into provaxml  (arquivo)
sELECT  CAST(BulkColumn AS XML) FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\2012-09\myfile.xml', SINGLE_BLOB)as arquivo
```

How i must write to change the filename by the variable @nome i have try this way but no works

```
 alter proc adentro (@nome nvarchar(max))as
insert into provaxml  (arquivo)
sELECT  CAST(BulkColumn AS XML) FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N @nome, SINGLE_BLOB)as arquivo
```

Thanks in advance

Alejandro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this...   (I just used this technique for a similar query yesterday)

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(4000);
SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO provaxml (arquivo) SELECT CAST(BulkColumn AS XML) FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''' + @nome + ''', SINGLE_BLOB) as arquivo';

EXEC( @sql );
```

I had this wrapped inside of a cursor (I know... I'm a bad boy for using a cursor.  But I think that this was a good use of one) so that I could populate my variable with a different filename each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks DeadZone i have write with this code and is working

ALTER proc [dbo].[adenti] (@entra nvarchar(max))as
DECLARE @sql varchar(4000);
SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO provaxml (arquivo) SELECT CAST(BulkColumn AS XML) FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''' + @entra + ''', SINGLE_BLOB) as arquivo';
EXEC( @sql );